# Converting String to Secret Key

Tags: java, type-conversion, byte, des

I want to transform a String value to secret KEY DES:

```
String sb="fffe7a50" //Example of DES key 
byte []b=sb.getBytes();  //string to bytes
SecretKey key2 = new SecretKeySpec(b, 0, b.length, "DES");
```

however the output is completly different :

```
javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@183a2
```

i know that the numbers after the "@" are supposed to be the DES key , but why are the results different ? how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few issues here:

1. `sb.getBytes()` *does not* do what you think it does. What you are expecting is a byte array containing `{ 0xff, 0xfe, 0x7a, 0x50 }`. What you are getting is a byte array containing `{ 0x46, 0x46, 0x46, 0x45, 0x37, 0x61, 0x35, 0x30 }` (assuming you're using UTF-8).

   Your choices here would be to either initialise the byte array manually, like so:

   ```
   byte[] b = new byte[]{ (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0x7a, (byte) 0x50 };
   ```

   Or to parse the string correctly. I'm not sure exactly how you'd go about that, but it should be doable (and there will likely be an open-source library to do it for you).
2. The output `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@183a2` is not writing out the value of the key. All you're seeing is the `toString` output of the `SecretKeySpec`, which follows the format `<fully-qualified-class-name>@<hashcode>` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) for details on the toString() method), so the numbers you're seeing, `183a2`, are just the hashcode of the `SecretKeySpec` object, which *must not* be the key - that would very insecure. To see the value of the key it's holding, you'd need to call the `SecretKeySpec#getEncoded()` method.

   Note that just calling `System.out.println(byteArray)` will not display the content of the byte array - it will just display the class name and hashcode again. You'll need to either iterate through the array and print out the elements one-by-one, or use another tool to compare the two arrays.